# change default template for sfGuard admin module- symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm using  symfony 1.4 (the lexpress symfony 1.5 branch) and sfPropelORMPlugin with propel 1.6
I've updated my admin generator backend to use  a bootstrap3 theme using this plugin:
https://github.com/bgcc/sfBootstrapPropelAdminThemePlugin

I set the admin to use this theme in the view.yml for each generated admin module.

thus:

```
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
    param:
      model_class:           Modelname
      theme:                 bootstrap
```

Can I set the theme globally for all admin modules somehow?

I've tried copying generator.yml into the application level config and just defining the template param but symfony wants a modelname.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but if you want to override plugin's module generator.yml, you just need to create `app/appName/modules/sfGuardUser/config/generator.yml` file and it will be used. Copy it from `plugins/sfGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardUser/config/generator.yml` and adjust. Same for other modules.